# thread-safe bloomfilter

Tags: java, guava

I am looking for a thread-safe BloomFilter implementation, i.e., an implementation that will behave exactly the same if values are put into the filter in sequence or simultaneously in parallel. The javadoc for guava's BloomFilter is silent about thread-safety. Is it thread-safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guava's `BloomFilter` isn't thread-safe.

That said, it's not 100% clear to me what semantics you'd expect for a thread-safe `BloomFilter` -- would `put` be atomic?  I'm imagining the effects of replacing the `long[]` with an `AtomicLongArray`, and I'm pretty sure the semantics you end up with are "if `put(x)` happens-before `mightContain(x)`, then `mightContain(x)` returns `true`," and I think those semantics are useful, but I'm not positive.

This might be worth [filing an issue](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/entry) with a specific use case, but there would be some details to work out about what thread-safety would mean here, exactly.

Comment: Yes, I realise that I was a bit ambiguous when I used the phrase "thread-safe". What I really want is something that gives me atomic but concurrent put and mightContain operations.

Since the underlying logic boils down to bit operations, I'd hope there would be some way for two puts to occur concurrently.

Comment: Ok, added issue as suggested: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1090

Comment: Version 23.0 of Guava is documented as thread-safe. In any case, thread-safety in certain Bloom Filter implementations (mine for example) are inherently thread-safe, in that there is no 'remove' operation and a collision would only result in (another) false-positive. Ref: https://guava.dev/releases/30.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.html

Comment: See also a bug report, which is really a bit misleading. While there are many implementations of BloomFilters, this particular report was based on the return from the 'put' itself versus actual concurrent corruption. Basic implementations just have an 'insert'  operation that do not return anything and are inherently thread-safe. See this comment from Guava dev (which is accurate): "... thread-safe based on the API that Bloom filters are generally advertised as having... implementation already guarantees that if put(elem) happens-before maybeContains(elem), then maybeContains ...returns true."

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the best solution is to patch an existing framework to make it thread-safe. But for a more immediate need, consider wrapping the non-thread-safe version in a thread-safe façade:

```
public class ThreadSafeBloomFilter {
  private BloomFilter filter;

  public ThreadSafeBloomFilter(BloomFilter filter) {
    this.filter = filter;
  }

  public synchronized void add(Object obj) {
    filter.add(obj);
  }
}
```

Implement the other methods you need in a similar manner. You probably also want to make it nice and generic as well (like a ThreadSafeBloomFilter, but that's your call).

In terms of performance, this will serialize all the requests, so you won't experience any performance gains by parallelizing access to it (and it could create a bottleneck).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem last week.

Ended up creating a wrapper class for guava bloom filter, where I created a number of filters. Then depending on key to insert I selected one of the filters and synchronized on that alone. Running with 256 filters and 8 concurrent threads I reached 90% CPU utilization even tho the added synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

I've adopted the Apache Cassandra version to support concurrent updates, as we required this property internally. You can check it out here: https://github.com/ifesdjeen/blomstre

Answer (score 0):

I made java library with different bloom filters, they all are **thread-safe**. Check it out. [ponkin/bloom](https://github.com/ponkin/bloom)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an early BloomFilter in Java (circa 1999) that is still in use today across many systems.

Since by their nature Bloom Filters can return false-positives in response to a contains() call, implementations like Guava realized there is actually no need for thread-safety. So the short answer to the OP question is whatever implementation there may be that has a thread-safe insert(key) method is a bit of a logical fallacy.

Consider the setup of a Bloom Filter:

A fixed size array of int (in my impl).
All keys are first hashed so they resolve to a consistent, fixed length (use MurmurHash in my impl).

So now two concurrent threads write two different values:

- They may produce the same hash value, producing a false-positive but
  upholding the contains(key) contract.
- Otherwise the different hash values will go into a different location
  in the array - so they can never corrupt one another partially or
  otherwise.